# Python - List comprehension based on two list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I would like to unhide or not in `list3` the letter behind "*" in `list2`, depending  on whether or not the letter chosen is in `list1`.  However, my list comprehension does not work.

My code in Python 3:

```
list1 = [ "h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]  
list2 = ["h", "*", "*", "*", "o"]  
letter_chosen = input("Choose a letter: ")  
list3 = [letter_chosen for letter in list1 if letter_chosen == letter else letter2 for letter2 in list2]
```

In the Python interpreter if I enter "l" as `letter_chosen`, I would like to have:

```
list3 = ["h", "*", "l", "l", "o"]
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be easier if you started with writing out a normal loop.

You want to do this:

```
for letter in list1:
    if letter_choosen == letter:
        letter   # picked letter, so add it to the output
    else:
        # not the picked letter, use the value from letter2 at the same position
```

The easiest way to do get the values from list2 is to use `zip()`; this pairs up the values from the two lists:

```
for letter, letter2 in zip(list1, list2):
    if letter_choosen == letter:
        letter   # picked letter, so add it to the output
    else:
        letter2  # not the picked letter, copy over the one from list2
```

Note that the `if` tests what value to add, so it is part of the *expression*. You could use a conditional expression instead:

```
for letter, letter2 in zip(list1, list2):
    letter if letter_choosen == letter else letter2
```

This then can be turned into a list comprehension:

```
[letter if letter_choosen == letter else letter2 for letter, letter2 in zip(list1, list2)]
```

or using more compact and comprehensible variable names:

```
goal = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
display = ["h", "*", "*", "*", "o"]
guess = input ("Choose a letter: ")  

new_display = [g if guess == g else d for g, d in zip(goal, display)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is invalid; you cannot loop on two lists at one time. Try using the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) command:

```
>>> list(zip(list1, list2))
[('h', 'h'), ('e', '*'), ('l', '*'), ('l', '*'), ('o', 'o')]
```

It will pair together items from both lists. So, your expression becomes:

```
>>> list3 = [letter_choosen if letter_choosen == letter1 else letter2 for (letter1, letter2) in zip(list1, list2)]
>>> list3
['h', '*', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
[letter if letter_choosen != letter else '*' for letter in list1]
```

Comment: This produces `'*'` entries for *everything but the current guess*, wiping out any previous correct guesses.